# How a clustering algorithm in R can end up with negative silhouette values? AB

Tags: cluster-analysis, silhouette

We know that clustering methods in R assign observations to the closest medoids. Hence, it is supposed to be the closest cluster each observation can have. So, I wonder how it is possible to have negative values of silhouette , while we are supposedly assign each observation to the closest cluster and the formula in silhouette method cannot get negative?

Behnam.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

1. most clustering algorithms do not use the medoid, only PAM does.
2. the silhouette does not use the distance to the medoid, but the *average distance* to all cluster members. If the closest cluster is very *wide*, the average distance can be larger than the distance to the medoid. Consider a cluster with one point in the center, and all others on a sphere around it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any better algorithm in mind to deal with large datasets? I am using Clara, but I still cannot use sample sizes larger than 10,000, practically and I have no way to choose sample size and number without try-and-error.

Comment: K-means is the most scalable, followed probably by DBSCAN.

Comment: I have the same problem with kmeans and all algorithms which need to construct large dissimilarity mattices.

Comment: Neither of them requires a large distance matrix.